# Ant fails to find junit for project generated with wsdl2java

Tags: ant, junit, apache-axis

I created a [axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) soap client project with unit tests using the following command:

```
wsdl2java -t -uri http://myDomain.tld/myService.svc?wsdl
```

I then ran `ant` and got build errors because it could not find junit methods such as fail(),assertNotNull(), etc. I realize I need the compiler to reference a junit jar. Looking in the `build.xml` I see the following:

```
<property name="classes" value="${build}/classes"/>
<property name="lib" value="${build}/lib"/>
```

So I place `junit-4.8.2.jar` in the build.lib subfolder. I still get the same errors. What else do I need to do to get ant to build my project?

**Update:**

I made the following changes to the build.xml:

Added the lib folder as a path with the id *local.class.path*

```
<path id="local.class.path">
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Then I modified my init task to look for junit:

```
    <available classpathref="local.class.path" property="junit.available" classname="junit.framework.TestCase"/>
    <condition property="jars.ok">
        <and>
            <isset property="stax.available"/>
            <isset property="axis2.available"/>
            <isset property="junit.available"/>
        </and>
    </condition>
    <!--Print out the availabilities-->
    <echo message="Stax Availability= ${stax.available}"/>
    <echo message="Axis2 Availability= ${axis2.available}"/>
    <echo message="JUnit Availability= ${junit.available}"/>
```

And strangely the output is:

```
H:\Code\Java\test.axis2> ant pre.compile.test
Buildfile: H:\Code\Java\RiskTools.axis2\build.xml

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: H:\Code\Java\test.axis2\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: H:\Code\Java\test.axis2\build\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: H:\Code\Java\test.axis2\build\lib

pre.compile.test:
     [echo] Stax Availability= true
     [echo] Axis2 Availability= true
     [echo] JUnit Availability= ${junit.available}

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

So it seems I am doing something wrong due to the line *[echo] JUnit Availability= ${junit.available}*

Comment: If you normally do `ant build`, may I suggest that you instead try

    ant -debug -verbose build >buildStdOut.txt

This will definitively show you whether junit-4.8.2 is being included.

Comment: rajah, Thats good information to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `build/lib` is the transient folder that gets blown away by `ant clean`. I made a folder called lib at the project root and then did the following to the build.xml.

In the root I added `<property name="dep_libs" value="${project.base.dir}/lib"/>`

I then change my path statement above to:

```
<path id="local.class.path">
    <fileset dir="${dep_libs}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

Then everything worked.